# How do I diagnose an error in my C code when my compiler doesn't tell me what's wrong?

Tags: mplab

the error is in the comments
When compiling it tells me that my code is wrong, but it doesn't tell me where.

I have changed the code several times and I can't find the error.

This is the code:

```c
// PIC18F4550 Configuration Bit Settings

// 'C' source line config statements

// CONFIG1L
#pragma config PLLDIV = 2       // PLL Prescaler Selection bits (Divide by 2 (8 MHz oscillator input))
#pragma config CPUDIV = OSC1_PLL2// System Clock Postscaler Selection bits ([Primary Oscillator Src: /1][96 MHz PLL Src: /2])
#pragma config USBDIV = 2       // USB Clock Selection bit (used in Full-Speed USB mode only; UCFG:FSEN = 1) (USB clock source comes from the 96 MHz PLL divided by 2)

// CONFIG1H
#pragma config FOSC = HSPLL_HS  // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator, PLL enabled (HSPLL))
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF      // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor disabled)
#pragma config IESO = OFF       // Internal/External Oscillator Switchover bit (Oscillator Switchover mode disabled)

// CONFIG2L
#pragma config PWRT = OFF       // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOR = OFF        // Brown-out Reset Enable bits (Brown-out Reset disabled in hardware and software)
#pragma config BORV = 3         // Brown-out Reset Voltage bits (Minimum setting 2.05V)
#pragma config VREGEN = OFF     // USB Voltage Regulator Enable bit (USB voltage regulator disabled)

// CONFIG2H
#pragma config WDT = OFF        // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled (control is placed on the SWDTEN bit))
#pragma config WDTPS = 32768    // Watchdog Timer Postscale Select bits (1:32768)

// CONFIG3H
#pragma config CCP2MX = OFF     // CCP2 MUX bit (CCP2 input/output is multiplexed with RB3)
#pragma config PBADEN = OFF     // PORTB A/D Enable bit (PORTB<4:0> pins are configured as digital I/O on Reset)
#pragma config LPT1OSC = OFF    // Low-Power Timer 1 Oscillator Enable bit (Timer1 configured for higher power operation)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // MCLR Pin Enable bit (MCLR pin enabled; RE3 input pin disabled)

// CONFIG4L
#pragma config STVREN = OFF     // Stack Full/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack full/underflow will not cause Reset)
#pragma config LVP = OFF        // Single-Supply ICSP Enable bit (Single-Supply ICSP disabled)
#pragma config ICPRT = OFF      // Dedicated In-Circuit Debug/Programming Port (ICPORT) Enable bit (ICPORT disabled)
#pragma config XINST = OFF      // Extended Instruction Set Enable bit (Instruction set extension and Indexed Addressing mode disabled (Legacy mode))

// CONFIG5L
#pragma config CP0 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CP1 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CP2 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CP3 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not code-protected)

// CONFIG5H
#pragma config CPB = OFF        // Boot Block Code Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM is not code-protected)

// CONFIG6L
#pragma config WRT0 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT1 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT2 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT3 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not write-protected)

// CONFIG6H
#pragma config WRTC = OFF       // Configuration Register Write Protection bit (Configuration registers (300000-3000FFh) are not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTB = OFF       // Boot Block Write Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTD = OFF       // Data EEPROM Write Protection bit (Data EEPROM is not write-protected)

// CONFIG7L
#pragma config EBTR0 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR1 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR2 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR3 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// CONFIG7H
#pragma config EBTRB = OFF      // Boot Block Table Read Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#define _STAL_FREQ 48000000
#include <xc.h>

void entradas_salidas (){
ADCON1bits.PCFG = 1111;
    
    TRISAbits.RA1 = 0;
    TRISAbits.RA3 = 0;
    TRISAbits.RA5 = 0;
    LATA = 0x00;
    TRISBbits.RB1 = 0;
    TRISBbits.RB4 = 0;
    TRISBbits.RB7 = 0;
    LATB = 0x00;
    TRISEbits.RE2 = 1;
    LATE = 0x00;


}

void cuerpo(){
    entradas_salidas();
    
    while(1)
    {
        if(PORTEbits.RE2 == 1)
        {}
        else
        {
            PORTA = 0b0100000;//rojo
            __deley_ms(8500);
            PORTA = 0x00;
            PORTA = 0b00010000;//verde
            PORTA = 0x00;
            PORTA = 0b00010000;
            __deley_ms(250);
            PORTA = 0x00;
            PORTA = 0b00010000;
            __deley_ms(250);
            PORTA = 0x00;
            PORTA = 0b00000001;
            __deley_ms(3000)
        }
        
        
        
    }
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
newmain.c:81:17: warning: implicit truncation from 'int' to bit-field changes value from 1111 to 7 [-Wbitfield-constant-conversion] ADCON1bits.PCFG = 1111;
newmain.c:107:13: warning: implicit declaration of function '__deley_ms' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration] __deley_ms(8500);
newmain.c:107:13: warning: implicit declaration of function '__deley_ms' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration] __deley_ms(8500);
newmain.c:118:29: error: expected ';' after expression __deley_ms(3000) 
2 warnings and 1 error generated.
```

It is still missing, but that is the basis, once that error has been solved I can continue.

What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: I edited your question to give it a more descriptive title and to add some small formatting changes. Could you please add the exact error message you're getting from the compiler? It might have information that would help someone diagnose the issue with your code. The [edit button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78206665/edit) is on the bottom of your post on the left side.

Comment: It won't let me put it in, but this is the error   make -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make  -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk dist/default/debug/Etapa2.debug.elf
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:95: build/default/debug/newmain.p1] Error 1
make[1]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:85: .build-conf] Error 2

Comment: make: *** [nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: .build-impl] Error 2
make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/tarea/MPLAB/Etapa2'
"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.46\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=18F4550 -c  -D__DEBUG=1  -mdebugger=none   -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v6.20/packs/Microchip/PIC18Fxxxx_DFP/1.6.159/xc8"  -fno-short-double -fno-short-float -memi=wordwrite -O0 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file

Comment: -ginhx32 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-download -mno-default-config-bits   -std=c99 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto:auto     -o build/default/debug/newmain.p1 newmain.c 
newmain.c:81:17: warning: implicit truncation from 'int' to bit-field changes value from 1111 to 7 [-Wbitfield-constant-conversion]
ADCON1bits.PCFG = 1111;  ^ ~~~~
newmain.c:107:13: warning: implicit declaration of function '__deley_ms' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
            __deley_ms(8500); ^ ~~~~
newmain.c:107:13:

Comment: warning: implicit declaration of function '__deley_ms' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
            __deley_ms(8500);newmain.c:118:29: error: expected ';' after expression
            __deley_ms(3000)
                            ^
                            ;
2 warnings and 1 error generated.
(908) exit status = 1
make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/tarea/MPLAB/Etapa2'

Comment: It didn't let me put it in one, that's why there were so many comments.

Comment: Alright, I copied and pasted your comments into the post. I didn't bother copying/formatting the build information. There are four lines that look like the main issues the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: I think the only thing preventing your code from compiling is the missing semicolon on the last call to `__deley_ms(3000)`, but the other warnings should probably be addressed too.

Comment: I'm a bit curious — why do you say it doesn't tell you where the error is? The error message seems pretty clear to me, and includes the line.

Comment: I agree after seeing the error. The compiler shows you exactly what's wrong and on what line. There is a skill to reading the error message, though, so it may just be that you're not used to parsing the compiler output yet. Don't worry, that comes with time.